# How do you store links outside Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a website that takes you to a random website. However, I couldn't really find any answers to store the links of websites outside javascript, forcing me to store them in the script itself. But this would become an issue in the future when I would need to navigate around the script and it's going to be difficult to work with. What should I do?

example script:

```
function clicked(){    
    window.open(links[Math.floor(Math.random()*max)]);
}

var links = [
    "linkexample.com",
    "linkexample2.com",
    "linkexample3.com"
];
```

Comment: How many URLs do you plan to have?  Might just be easiest to have a JSON file that you get with `fetch()` if it's not too long.  Otherwise, you can do something server-side.

Comment: Put them in a file or database on the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate around the script"?

Comment: I am thinking of adding hundreds of links and scrolling through them could be annoying later

Answer (score 0):

- Like the last comment said the best way is to store them in your server script to access them with ajax here's an example of `Nodejs` server script and `js` browser Script

> Nodejs

```
const express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.post("/links", (req, res) => { 
  var links = [
    "linkexample.com",
    "linkexample2.com",
    "linkexample3.com"
   ];
   links = JSON.stringify(links);
   res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
   res.send(links)
});
app.listen(3000, "localhost");
```

> JS Browser Script

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onloadend = function(e) { 
  //You can see your links array in the console
  //You can also use JSON.parse() to parse the array in you script and use it
  console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText)
}
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/links", true)
xhr.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, everyone for answering. I managed to figure out my own solution which was to create an additional javascript file just for the links then get the value from there

external.js

```
var links = [
    "linkexample.com",
    "linkexample2.com",
    "linkexample3.com"       
];
```

main.js

```
function clicked(){    
    window.open(links[Math.floor(Math.random()* links.length)]);
}
```

I changed the max variable since it wasn't working for some reasons but at least it works perfectly now :D